# Define classes without using the class keyword in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm a TypeScript newbie and the following is a question of curiosity mostly.

Before ES6, JavaScript had no classes. Thus, I would expect to be able to get away with not using in TypeScript as well.

Yet, I don't find the right way of doing it. Take this sample class:

```
class FooConcrete {
    getImpl : () => number;

    constructor(getImpl: () => number) {
        this.getImpl = getImpl;
    }

    get() : number {
        return this.getImpl();
    }
}
```

Since type definition files usually expose something like the following, I start with that:

```
interface FooConcrete
{
    get() : number;
}

interface FooConcreteStatic
{
    new () : FooConcrete;
}
```

But how do I then define the constructor function `FooConcrete`?

I tried:

```
var FooConcrete : FooConcreteStatic = function FooConcrete() {
    return {
        get: () => 42
    };
};
```

That doesn't compile though, although the corresponding Javascript works as intended:

```
new FooConcrete().get() // => 42
```

Is there a way to declare `FooConcrete` as `FooConcreteStatic` without writing it as a class?

(The motivation behind the case was that I was curious to see if there was a way to get rid of the spurious redirection in the class from the prototype's `get` to the implementation `getImpl` - in this case there's no need for a `get` in a prototype.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you can't do that without tricking the compiler, because the language does the work for you if you use classes.

Your typescript class code:

```
class FooConcrete {
    getImpl : () => number;

    constructor(getImpl: () => number) {
        this.getImpl = getImpl;
    }

    get() : number {
        return this.getImpl();
    }
}
```

compiles into this when targeting es5:

```
var FooConcrete = (function () {
    function FooConcrete(getImpl) {
        this.getImpl = getImpl;
    }
    FooConcrete.prototype.get = function () {
        return this.getImpl();
    };
    return FooConcrete;
}());
```

And the definition file:

```
declare class FooConcrete {
    getImpl: () => number;
    constructor(getImpl: () => number);
    get(): number;
}
```

The js output is pretty much what you wanted to do (just with prototype which is the "right" way to go), and the definition uses `declare class` and not with interfaces as you pointed out.

This approach results in cleaner codeand the ability to compile it into es5 classes or es6 classes.